# What are the approaches to add an import or include support to a programming language?

Tags: compiler-construction, python-import, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I am implementing an interpreter as hobby project nowadays using tutorials. Basically, I lex, parse code and produce an abstract syntax tree and evaluate it. From one source code file, I generate 1 tree. Now I want to add a functionality similar to Python's import or C's #include statement. What are my approaches? How other languages overcome this problem? Are they creating two separate trees and combine them or just copy a file's content to the actual file and create one big tree? Can you give me any tutorial or paper that explains the possible approaches?

Answer (score 1):

The solution does depend on whether the `includes` are signatures, or headers, for functions (like C, etc.) or source bodies (like Java).

### Include as header or signatures

- Lex and check for any `include` statements
- Load any includes and create a symbol table for each and put in stack (subjective implementation warning). No need to create a full AST for each as only the symbols are important for resolving references.
- During parse and AST emit, use the stack of symbol tables for lookups

The assumptions are: That which make up the `include` has already been parsed, verified and code emitted from it's source.

### Includes as source

When you include source you are extending your compilation unit and the imported source would be considered `in scope`. This would entail:

- Lex the base source
- Identify, load and lex the included source. This should `pre-pend` your lex token list unless you have specific behaviors as part of your language semantic
- Proceed to now generate your one (1) AST. It will just be bigger.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two general approaches compilers take the "include" problem.

1. Literally include the text of the file. That is the approach C and enhanced FORTRAN 77 compilers used.
2. Compile the "include" separately and just include the definitions. That is the approach Ada takes.

Some compilers use both. There are some compilers (e.g. some Pascals) that support both methods.